# Ajax Post Filter with WP_Query only fires once with Category

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax post filter modeled after [this article](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html). I have it working mostly as desired but I wanted to be able to filter lectures by a category (it is actually a sub-category but I don't know if that makes any difference).

I have filters for speaker and for the latest lectures and those work fine, but when I try to run the Series filter (the part with elseif( isset( $_POST['series_name'] ) ) ) I get no response. If try running the Series filter first it will fire once but then will not respond. If I try running any other filter first they will work fine but then the Series filter will not fire at all. I think my problem is how I'm handling the $args for the WP_Query for when $_POST['series_name'] is set.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is my php:

```
function lectures_filter_function(){
$i = 1;
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'lectures',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'lecture_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'       
); 

if( isset( $_POST['speaker'] ) ) 
{
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'speaker',
        'value' => $_POST['speaker'],
    );
} 
elseif( isset( $_POST['series_name'] ) ) 
{
    //*This is how I wanted to code it but it didn't work at all*
    // $args['tax_query'] = array(
    //      array(
    //          'taxonomy' => 'category',
    //          'value' => 'category_name',
    //          'terms' => $_POST['series_name']
    //      )
    //  );

    //This is how I at least got it to fire once per screen load.
    $args = array(
                'category_name' => $_POST['series_name'],
                'post_type' => 'lectures',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'meta_key' => 'lecture_date',
                'order' => 'DESC'                   
        );      
}


    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $postlist = $the_query->post_count;

    // The Query

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            // print_r($the_query);

            if($i % 2 == 1){
                echo '<div class="row">';
            }   
        ?>      

        <div class="large-6 columns lecture-tile">
            <div class="lecture-overlay-container">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <div class="lecture-tile-overlay"></div>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
                    <div class="lecture-tile-info">
                        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>

<?php 
    $current_id = get_the_id();
    $lecture_type = get_post_meta($current_id, 'lecture_type', true);
    if($lecture_type == "Single"){
        $lecture_descriptor = "lecture";
    }elseif ($lecture_type == 'Series') {
        $series_name = get_post_meta($current_id, 'series_name', true);
        $lecture_descriptor = $series_name;
    }elseif ($lecture_type == 'Event') {
        $event_name = get_post_meta($current_id, 'event_name', true);
        $lecture_descriptor = $event_name;
    }           
?>                              
                        <p><?php echo $lecture_descriptor; ?></p>                           
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <?php
                if($i % 2 == 0 || $i == $num_posts){
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                $i++;
        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // no posts found
        echo "No matching lectures found...";
    }
die();
```

}

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'lectures_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'lectures_filter_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'actor',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. From your example I came up with 
`$terms = strtolower($_POST['series_name']);

  $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'lectures',

        'orderby' => 'meta_value',

        'meta_key' => 'lecture_date',

     'order' => 'DESC', 
    
     'tax_query' => array(

      array(

       'taxonomy' => 'category',

       'field' => 'slug',

       'terms' => $terms,

      ),
     ),
   );`

Comment: And it was the same as before, the ajax fired once then broke whenever I tried to use series again, or works fine without series filter. I think maybe the problem could be in my form but I copied the format from the speakers filter.

Comment: try to this <br/>

Comment: $category = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'category')